# Display value from Database to TextBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, listview, textbox

I have a listview that display all EmpID and EmpName from database. How I will view the value from database to textbox when I click on a row? This is how I display the selected row from listview to textBox.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
    EmpIDtextBox.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
    EmpNametextBox.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
}
else
{
    EmpIDtextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    EmpNametextBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
}
```

The listview don't have Address, Age and other fields. How I display the Address and other fields that listview does not contains in textBox?

Comment: The best solution is that you load all the data and bind it to the tag of ListViewRow.And when you click on any row in listview just fetch the tag and parse it to the object of type tag and show the values in textbox. It will save you from sending multiple calls to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind your list to a data source which contains all data you need..and if you do not want to show a column in the list make the width of that column 0,then it will hide..then you can fill the textboxes like this: for example

```
EmpAge.Text = item.subItems[3].Text ;//column's width is 0

EmpAddress.Text = item.subItems[4].Text ;//column's width is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

When you fill `ListView` with data you can put `DataRow` (or another object that keep all data row information) to Tag property of `ListViewItem`.

```
item.Tag = row;
```

Then when user selects row in list view you can get `DataRow` from Tag property of the selected `ListViewItem` and extract property values from this data row, like this:

```
var row = item.Tag as DataRow.
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do :

```
/*declare variable with scope global */
 int id;

if (Listview.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem item;

            item = ListProducts.SelectedItems[0];
             id = int.parse(item.SubItems[0].Text.ToString());
            }
 SqlCommand cmd = "SELECT Address, Age FROM table2 WHERE id= @item";
 cmd.Connection = YourDataBaseConnection;
 cmd.Parameters.Clear();
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.Int).Value= id;
 con.Open();
 sqlDataReader rdr = new SqlDataReader();
 rdr= cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while(rdr.Read())
 {
   yourTextBox.Text = rdr[0].Text.Tostring();
   //place the data to desired textBox
 }
 con.Dispose();
 cmd.Dispose();
```

`